# How to implement restriction on accessing appliction feature based on plan

Tags: nestjs, access-control

I am currently developing an application in nestjs, that provides services to the user. User selects a plan user will get access to features based on limit defined by plan.

As an example: let us assume there are **three plans** and **4 features**

- user with plan A can access feature A,B
- user with plan B can access A,B,C.
- user with plan C can access A,B,C,D.

So I am looking for the best way to get this done, and main concerns are following:-

- maintainability/changeability: Should be able to increase plan and its feature in future.
- efficiency

I have never implemented such functionality before, so I have no clue about how do I go to implement this feature. Any tips/guides/examples? I have studied about RBAC and ACL.

Thanks in advance